# E-mail autofill with VB.net

Tags: email

I'm using VB.net for my project. I'm trying to get it so that emails that get sent to an account will automatically fill in some information. The emails would be from people booking online for bedrooms at this B'n'B/hotel. Is there anyway this can happen?

Comment: Could you focus on more specific part of your application and provide sample code you wrote?

Comment: I haven't created any code yet, I'm just about getting to the design of the system. And I was just wondering if this is even possible.
The specific part is would it be possible for specific information in the email to be saved to a file location and then be loaded be loaded back up by the system.